# '~' operator in Numpy used for general condition?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I recently came across this operator in a data analysis book that I should have read a long time ago. It is used for general conditions but I don't understand it.

Comment: Is the logical not operator

Comment: Have you considered just reading the documentation?

Comment: There are no numpy operators. Numpy is a python library. The python interpreter handles all operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When applied to a numpy array with boolean dtype, it is the logical_not operator:

```
In [607]: np.array([True, False, True])                                                              
Out[607]: array([ True, False,  True])
In [608]: ~np.array([True, False, True])                                                             
Out[608]: array([False,  True, False])
In [611]: np.logical_not(np.array([True, False, True]))                                              
Out[611]: array([False,  True, False])
```

That's not the case with Python booleans:

```
In [613]: ~True                                                                                      
Out[613]: -2
In [614]: not True                                                                                   
Out[614]: False
```